# Realm result showing [dbRealm = proxy[{points:[1]}] instead of number

Tags: java, android, realm

My TextView `show` is showing the realm results as `[dbRealm = proxy[{points:[1]}], [dbRealm = proxy[{points:[2]}], [dbRealm = proxy[{points:[3]}],` etc... everytime I click. How can I make it show only the number I want instead of `[dbRealm = proxy[{points:[1]}]`?

Java code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        Realm.init(getActivity());

        RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("dbRealm.realm")
                .schemaVersion(0)
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        ConstraintLayout content2 = view.findViewById(R.id.content2);
        TextView show = view.findViewById(R.id.show);
        Button removebut = view.findViewById(R.id.removebut);

        final TextView pointsText = view.findViewById(R.id.pointsText);
        final int[] hit = {0};
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

        content2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hit[0]++;
            pointsText.setText(String.valueOf(hit[0]));

                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                            final dbRealm getPoints = realm.createObject(dbRealm.class);
                            getPoints.setPoints(Arrays.toString(hit));
                            realm.insertOrUpdate(getPoints);
                        }
                    });

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Botão +1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

        RealmResults<dbRealm> results = realm.where(dbRealm.class).findAllAsync();
        results.load();

        removebut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                        RealmResults<dbRealm> results = realm.where(dbRealm.class).findAllAsync();
                        results.load();
                        results.deleteAllFromRealm();
                    }
                });
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Removido", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        show.setText(results.toString());
        return view;

    }
```

dbRealm.java:

```
import io.realm.RealmObject;

/**
 * Created by MateusPC1 on 19/03/2018.
 */

public class dbRealm extends RealmObject{

    private String points;

    public String getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    void setPoints(String points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `show.setText(results.toString());`, you should be showing the value in the object obtained from the results.

So something like

```
dbRealm pointObject = results.get(0);
show.setText(pointObject.getPoints());
```

Although your model probably doesn't actually model what you want to do. Probably you might want to do something like

```
public class dbRealm extends RealmObject{
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id; // null is a valid id and we will use it here

    private RealmList<Long> points; // Realm 4.0.0+

    public RealmList<Long> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
}

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
         .initialData((realm) -> {
             realm.createObject(dbRealm.class, null);
         })
         .deleteIfMigrationNeeded() // todo: make sure you can have this
         .build();
```

and then

```
    content2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        ...

                realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                        final dbRealm getPoints = realm.where(dbRealm.class).findFirst();
                        RealmList<Long> points = getPoints.getPoints();
                        points.clear();
                        points.add(hit[0]);
                    }
                });

    removebut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(@NonNull Realm realm) {
                     final dbRealm getPoints = realm.where(dbRealm.class).findFirst();
                     RealmList<Long> points = getPoints.getPoints();
                     points.clear();
                }
           });
       }
```

Comment: Hi! After making those changes, I got a few errors: the two lines                         ' RealmList<Long> points = getPoints.getPoints(); ' are gaving me "Method invocation 'getPoints' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'" and on ' show.setText(pointObject.getPoints()); ', I'm getting "Cannot resolve method 'setText(io.realm.RealmList<java.lang.Long>)'"

Comment: It gave me the error "cannot resolve method 'toString(io.realm.RealmList<java.lang.Long>)'", then the program suggested to surround with array initialization and it became show.setText(Arrays.toString(new RealmList[]{pointObject.getPoints()})); 
Now it's only showing the text one time as it should be, but it's showing "[RealmList<java.lang.Long>@[1]]" instead of "1".

Comment: Actually, use `setText(Arrays.toString(pointObject.getPoints().toArray()))` then

Comment: It worked! But now it's showing [1] instead of "1" haha.
One question: Why is getPoints() giving me "Method invocation 'getPoints' may produce 'java.lang.NullPointerException'"? I read about it by pressing Ctrl+F1 but I still don't understand.

Comment: Because the IDE doesn't know that you are going to be using managed Realm objects in which case `RealmList<Integer>` is never null.

Comment: Oh, I see. It's OK then. :) About the [1], any way to remove the [ ] ?

Comment: If you build your own String with StringBuilder instead of using `Arrays.toString()`